# Why is lookup in dictionary much faster than two if-tests in Python?

Tags: python, performance, dictionary

I need to read gigabytes of text so I'm trying to optimize my code. When doing this I found that, for my problem, using a dictionary is faster than if-tests.

```
check = {'R':'-', 'F':'+'}
seqs = ['R', 'F']*100

def check1():
    for entry in seqs:
        if entry == 'R':
            strand = '-'
        if entry == 'F':
            strand = '+'

def check2():
    for entry in seqs:
        strand = check[entry]
```

Using ipythong's %timeit I see that looking up in a dictionary is slightly more than twice as fast as using two if-tests:

```
In [63]: %timeit check1()
10000 loops, best of 3: 38.8 us per loop

In [64]: %timeit check2()
100000 loops, best of 3: 16.2 us per loop
```

Since if-tests are so basic, I did not expect a performance difference. Is this well known? Can anybody explain why this is so?

**UPDATE**

I checked how the two functions above as well as check3() below affect the runtime of my actual code, and there's no effect on the total time. So either the boost gotten with the dictionary is not so high in a real-world example where the 'R' and 'F' values need to be re-read from file constantly, or this piece of code is just not part of my bottleneck.

Anyway thanks for the answers!

Comment: `chedict` is an undefined variable.  What -- exactly -- are you timing?

Comment: I guess it has to do with the fact that x == y is in fact a function call (`x.__eq__`), and two function calls are more expensive than a dict lookup in python.

Comment: S.Lott: Sorry it's a typo. I have updated the text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with a lot of VM code, it mostly comes down to the number of VM opcodes involved.

You can examine the assembled functions with `dis`:

```
import dis
dis.dis(func)
```

In 2.6.4, check1 takes around 15-20 opcodes (depending on the code path), for each comparison and branch.  check2 takes just 7 (after adding the missing `chedict` dictionary, declared globally).

Answer (score 7):

You haven't actually proved that looking up in a dictionary is faster than two `if` tests. What you have shown is that looking up in that particular dictionary is faster than those two tests.

Normally dictionary lookup needs a few steps: generate a hash from the key to find a potential match, then test the potential match by comparing the keys. Sometimes it may have to do multiple comparisons if there are hash table collisions. If you have user defined classes for the keys then both of these steps could be slow, they are generally fast for strings but in one particular case they are really really fast, and you've hit that case.

Your dictionary uses keys that are short strings that match the format for identifiers known at compile time. Python will helpfully 'intern' your strings 'R' and 'F'. Since the strings you use in your tests are also known at compile time they will be the exact same instances. What all this means for dictionary lookup is that a specialised version of the lookup is used for a dictionary which has only string keys, the hash has always been precomputed, and key comparison is done by comparing addresses (at least when it succeeds and with your two keys it will never fail).

Your real code will, I assume be reading strings from the input, so it won't have the interned copy of 'R'. That means it will need to compute the hash for each line of input. The addresses won't match so it will have to call the string comparison function for each test. You do still get some optimisations for having only string keys and at least it doesn't have to do the general purpose comparison for objects which might not be strings.

The `if` statements know nothing about the object types so they do do a general purpose comparison every time.

Comment: That's useful to know. I'll try to benchmark my real solution.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries are heavily optimized in Python; lookup is `O(1)` - it's just a hashtable lookup and therefore just one "operation" - half the number of operations you get with your sequence of `if` tests (which is `O(n)`).

Answer (score 1):

Would this reveal something:

```
def check3():
    for entry in seqs:
        if entry == 'R':
            strand = '-'
        else:
            strand = '+'
```

It's actually faster than `check2()` on my computer.

Comment: On mine it is 10% slower than check2(). This alone would be a big improvement though, as I know I only have 'R's and 'F's to check for.